# Logical analysis of the incipit of Proust's "In the Shadow of Young Girls in Flower"

Tags: grammaire, constructions

I cannot understand the sentence construction (subject, direct object, etc.) of the incipit of Proust's "In the Shadow of Young Girls in Flower" (À l’ombre des jeunes filles en fleurs):

> Ma mère, quand il fut question d’avoir pour la première fois M. de Norpois à dîner, ayant exprimé le regret que le Professeur Cottard fût en voyage et qu’elle-même eût entièrement cessé de fréquenter Swann, car l’un et l’autre eussent sans doute intéressé l’ancien ambassadeur, mon père répondit qu’un convive éminent, un savant illustre, comme Cottard, ne pouvait jamais mal faire dans un dîner, mais que Swann, avec son ostentation, avec sa manière de crier sur les toits ses moindres relations, était un vulgaire esbroufeur que le Marquis de Norpois eût sans doute trouvé, selon son expression, « puant ».

I would think that the father replies to the mother, but it is "répondre à quelqu'un" and not "répondre quelqu'un".

Comment: Why do you think *répondit* has an obect in that sentence? (Aside from maybe an implicit one: *à ma mère*.)

Comment: Ok, maybe I can ask better: _what_ is the logical role of _Ma mère_?

Comment: Ah! I now understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction is:

- Ma mère … ayant exprimé le regret que …
- mon père répondit qu[e] …

So something like “After my mother … expressed her disappointment that … my father replied that….”

Comment: Great! So is it actually something like "Ma mère ayant exprimé le regret que.., mon père [LUI] répondit que.."? I mean, that would also be correct and have the same meaning?

Comment: @fra_pero — Yes, but leaving the pronoun _lui_ out is more idiomatic (at least in this sentence). It’s the same in English. We _could_ write “my father replied to her that…” but the words “to her” are in fact completely superfluous.

Answer (score 5):

*Complement to [user Segorian's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52584/17649)*

"Ma mère" is the subject in the following non finite clause ("*proposition participe*").

- *Ma mère, quand il fut question d’avoir pour la première fois M. de Norpois à dîner, ayant exprimé le regret que le Professeur Cottard fût en voyage et qu’elle-même eût entièrement cessé de fréquenter Swann, car l’un et l’autre eussent sans doute intéressé l’ancien ambassadeur*,

The function of this non finite clause is "*complément circonstanciel de cause du verbe « répondre »*"; in the grammar of English this corresponds to the function of *adverbial (causal)*; in the terminology of *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, this adverbial would be called a *cause adjunct*, and the translation of the clause could also be made by means of a non finite clause.

The verb in this clause is "*ayant exprimé*", in the  "mode participe" and the "*forme  passé composé*" (which is not a tense but simply a "form"); the term "*participe passé composé*" is the name of the grammatical category of this verbal phrase. The subject of this clause is "ma mère".

The verb of the sentence is "*répondit*" and its subject is "*mon père*".

This verb *does* have an object (cod); it is the long completive clause introduced by "*que*" (« qu' ») ("*proposition subordonnée complétive*" in French).

- *qu’un convive éminent, un savant illustre, comme Cottard, ne pouvait jamais mal faire dans un dîner, mais que Swann, avec son ostentation, avec sa manière de crier sur les toits ses moindres relations, était un vulgaire esbroufeur que le Marquis de Norpois eût sans doute trouvé, selon son expression, « puant ».*

<sub>**Note** re [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52583/logical-analysis-of-the-incipit-of-prousts-in-the-shadow-of-young-girls-in-flo#comment110017_52584) (*So is it actually something like "Ma mère ayant exprimé le regret que.., mon père [LUI] répondit que.."? I mean, that would also be correct and have the same meaning?*)

This is not necessarily a conversation between the mother and the father, in which case "lui" would change nothing to the extra-linguistic context. It is more probable, in fact, that this long sentence is a reminiscence concerning a conversation among a group, and the person to whom the mother was speaking might also have been the person to whom the father's reply was made.

([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9pondre)) − Répondre que + ind. • M. Churchill m'a écrit pour me demander l'engagement en Libye d'une grande unité française. Je lui ai répondu que je donnais volontiers les ordres nécessaires (De Gaulle, Mém. guerre, 1954, p. 640).</sub>